# Why does the fridge thermostat have an inverted scale?

Tags: usability

In all fridges that I've ever encountered which had a manual thermostat, the scale on the thermostat was a scale of "inverse temperature":

- 1 means keep the fridge hotter
- 5 means keep the fridge colder

[image: The knob]

**Why is it like that?**

Note that on the manual the producer "cheats", specifying it's a scale of power (5 => more power => colder), but of course the actual knob controls a thermostat.

(Of course, modern fridges don't have a knob any more and they just set themselves to 3-4°C.)

Comment: It seems logical to me.  The point of a fridge is to make things colder - so you "turn it up" to make it even colder.

Comment: you're not alone. I'm always confused by fridge thermostats (embarrassed face)

Comment: I've seen some other questions touching on similar problems you may find interesting: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/is-a-grayscale-bar-a-bad-way-of-showing-temperature and also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75890/why-do-showers-have-hot-and-cold-knobs-rather-than-temperature-and-quanti

Comment: Kind of the same reason that you don't turn the volume down to 1 in order to make it less quiet.

Comment: It also correlates to energy usage. The colder it is, the more energy it uses. If a "1" setting at 4 degrees is good enough, why waste more energy and turn it up?

Comment: Why does a refrigerator need a dial at all? Why can't they just figure out the best temperature, and make it that all the time? I have no idea what my fridge is set to, and have never thought of changing it. (Good question, btw)

Comment: @Trevor Different foods work better in different temperatures. Of course, that's what led to fridges that have different temperatures in different sections - although most people don't know how to use that anyway. More importantly, different people have different preferences - say, for the optimal temperature of their favourite cool beverage.

Comment: I think the real question here is: _does it go up to eleven?_

Comment: @Trevor an infrequently-opened fridge will be fine sitting at 5° and occasionally going warmer when opened, especially if storing nothing more perishable than say milk.  A fridge which is frequently opened and is used for raw meat (e.g. in a household that drinks a lot of chilled drinks) should be set colder so that the temperature when left closed for a while is say 2° and it doesn't warm up to spoilage temperatures easily.

Comment: I still vote for an "auto" mode.

Comment: I wonder if people designing this didn't think in terms of UX, and just did it because it "makes" sense.  Maybe they themselves were the use case and it made sense to them to do it that way.

Comment: I agree with @Trevor. If the refrigerator cannot automatically sense the contents of a compartment, because that’s too unreliable or too expensive, there should be iconic switches or buttons for (raw) meat, milk/dairy, drinks, vegetables, fruit, … for (and adjacent to) each compartment/zone. These interfaces could double as indicators for the optimal type of content.

Comment: surprised no one mentioned Don Norman.  Read the Book, Design of Everyday Things, and this is covered.  You can see an image from it here http://image.slidesharecdn.com/baobab-cognitive-lecture-201403160539-140320104816-phpapp01/95/usability-cognitive-factors-baobab-health-trust-march-2014-38-638.jpg?cb=1419861469

Comment: @MonkeyZeus funny you should pick that example... are you aware that in professional audio, 0 is often the _loudest_ setting? The quietest is something like -120 (or indeed -∞, meaning silence), but the minus sign is sometimes omitted. The scale denotes _attenuation_ in [dB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel).

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's quite interesting, I was not aware of that! It sounds like the marketing department got a hold of the volume knob before releasing it to the public. Overall, it is an easier concept to grasp because it is a measurement of sound; 0 is nothing so no sound and 10/11 is more than 0 so it's more sound. I wonder if we would live in a nicer world if people were to says things like "Hey, could you please decrease the attenuation? I am trying to concentrate."

Comment: @Trevor, not UX related, but you should invest in a fridge thermometer. Fridges can very wildly in temp based on location, usage, how full they are, etc.

Comment: BTW, "why" this is is the same reason most of these types of questions asking about product design on this site are that way: because of a *lack* of UX. As such, I wouldn't really call this a UX question. That said, Tohster's answer is very UX appropriate so think it should stay.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Because crappy designers are everywhere

There is almost no excuse for this kind of ambiguous, uncommunicative control labeling when there are so many better patterns to follow with fridge thermostats.

Here are some control formats that are far more effective.

- They communicate the polarity of coldness clearly
- They are color-blind friendly (some use shapes and/or labelling in addition to color)
- Most of them are language and celsius/farenheit independent, for international products
- Most of them can be printed using just 1 color, if cost is an isssue.
- Most of them don't rely on a thermostatic controller (i.e. no exact temperature), although for completeness I've included one example with a temperature setting and indication for recommended temperature.

[image: alternatives]

There are pros and cons to each of these alternatives, and this list is not intended to be exhaustive.  But they are all better than a naked 1-to-5 rating.

Personally I would pick a numberless volume label (either top left or 2nd from bottom, left) as it is likely to be most universally communicative.

Comment: Bottom-left format is not international-friendly. I have no idea how cold 35F is (granted, I wouldn't know how good 1.5°C is as far a fridge temperatures are concerned, but that's a different flaw of showing actual temperatures)

Comment: @3Doubloons it's a rather pedantic point as numbers in general aren't "international friendly" in that sense (Japanese, Chinese, Arabic, etc).  The point of the illustration was to show the design pattern, not the specific format of the number which in this case will need to be tailored for the region or, alternatively, replaced with one of the other non-language specific patterns.

Comment: The three iconographic examples would make me think harder than a 1-5 scale ("more snowflakes please"). The numeric example is incorrect for a dial because those old dial-type thermostats were not accurate to the degree and they might vary over the life of the product.

Comment: @plainclothes for consumer products it's more important to communicate clearly than to communicate efficiently.  For example, if `1-5` is faster for you but is confusing to 20% of users, it is still a bad solution.  For the numeric control, better fridges have extremely dependable thermostatic controls...if the thermostat is inaccurate or drifts then it should be obvious that the designer should not use a numeric control to begin with!

Comment: Yup, that's what the OP is talking about: old school rheostat type controls, not modern, degree-accurate units where a meaningful numbers can be provided. And it should be noted that a percentage of users will always be slower at comprehension than others. That's why the fridge comes set from the factory.

Comment: Sigh.  I knew someone would have a nitpicking problem with the numeric example which is why I tried to qualify that answer explicitly with the note on thermostatic controllers.  Factory settings cannot be relied on:  if a product is going to have a control on it, then it cannot assume slow users will not touch the control.  The control needs to be clearly and unambiguously labeled, period.  That's even more true if food safety is a consequence of user action.

Comment: No one is nitpicking: The question is about a rheostat device -- no hard numbers allowed. More importantly, your examples all work against user expectations: A refrigerator "produces coldness" so turning the dial down or moving it to the left would indicate "produce less coldness". I think it would be good fun to watch a user lab test of these designs, but I don't think it would be a success.

Comment: The question is **NOT** about  a rheostat device specifically.  The OP simply said a manual thermostat control. They are not the same.  Having designed, critiqued, and invested in a lot of consumer product interfaces over the years I am sure of the design logic here.  Modern fridges have moved away from pure number controls towards either a combination of numbers and volume/color/snowflake graphics or a numberless scheme with false breaks to avoid continuum disorientation for users with analog controls. The schematics are intended to be for on-bezel labels so moving RIGHT makes it colder.

Comment: @3Doubloons The bottom right is also not internationally friendly, because those symbols are are typically used for freezer compartment strengths.

Comment: To clarify: there's no rheostat in such "old fridges", it's just a thermostat with the weird "1-5" scale mapping (inversely) somewhere between the 2-6°C range, I guess, and with no guarantees of accuracy. The engine runs always at full power until the thermostat hits and stops it. Modern fridges can tune the engine power, are automatically set to hit 3-4°C and stay there, have multiple temperature sensors inside of it, make the air flow around to keep the temperature uniform and prevent icing... they're not the case in question. :)

Comment: @tohster: I think the topleft makes sense (and it's again a scale of "coolness" -- more cool to less cool). The cold/hot one doesn't make sense for a fridge (there's no hot, just cold and colder). The scale in °F (or in °C, for that matter) is fine, but implies a precision in the measurament that old thermostats don't have (and I don't think you want to write 3 - 3.5 - 4 - 4.5 - 5 °C...). The one in the bottom right clashes with the equivalent symbols on a freezer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerator#Temperature_zones_and_ratings

Comment: I have a (room) thermostat that gives °C at the bottom, top and middle -- let's say 18°C---25°C---32°C as I can't remember the exact numbers.  That format would leave enough room to give °C and °F (UK) even if you had a °C (most of Europe) and °F (US) dial as well, and avoids the spurious precision -- the numbers are centred on missing tick marks and tick marks are widely spaced.

Comment: @peppe: Even if the designers of my fridge thought so, I don't think the word "cold" is indicative of the highest-temperature end of a device's operating range.  I can't think any single word that's really good, but I think "less cold" would be relatively unambiguous.

Comment: @tohster Maybe I've been misreading your illustrations all along. You said *"The schematics are intended to be for on-bezel labels so **moving RIGHT makes it colder**."* That would make sense, but they all seem to be oriented in the opposite direction.

Comment: @plainclothes yes.  On-bezel markings look like this:  http://i.imgur.com/m4o3M2c.png.  Moving the thumbwheel to the right makes the fridge closer.  The polarity reverses depending on whether the label is on the control or on the housing.

Comment: @tohster I'm with you now! Right is good.

Comment: I don't find *any* of those clear at all, except the one giving degree numbers, which has other issues of course. (Just for reference: I'm not color-blind, I grew up in the U.S., and my native language is English. So it's not that I'm used to reading right-to-left or something [to pick a random example].)

Answer (score 52):

**It matches the user's mental model, which is more important than matching real-world circumstances.**

Users view a refrigerator as something that "makes cold". Therefore the number 5 corresponds to "more cold" and 1 to "less cold".

The mental model of "a device that holds its interior at a constant temperature" is more complex and harder to reconcile with things like ambient temperature and what happens when you put hot food in a cold fridge.

Labeling the dial with an explicit temperature range would be possible, but users probably don't know the specific temperature they need, and manufacturers would have to make dials in both Celsius and Fahrenheit to be able to sell internationally.

Comment: Seems like the 'power of coldness' idea is a bit confusing for people though. Couldn't we have a blue to red scale or something instead, albeit with red being quite small? I always though that it was degrees on my old fridge...like 1-5 degree celsius

Comment: It obviously *doesn't* match some users' mental models.  Tyranny of the majority.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26663/discussion-on-answer-by-nathan-rabe-why-does-the-fridge-thermostat-have-an-inver).

Comment: -1 This is actually not a correct answer. The thing is, it *doesn't* match the mental model. The mental model of a dial that affects a thermostat is = higher the number, the hotter it is.

Comment: I turn up an air conditioner, I expect it to get colder.  Same as a refrigerator.  I'm afraid that different people have different models, and the manufacturer caters to whichever they perceive as most common.  Nothing stopping them from making it more explicit, though.

Answer (score 4):

Tohster's answer is great. Vote for that one. But to address the 'mental model' aspect in another answer:

The reason the dial is the way it is is that it's not a thermostat. It's actually a 'power' dial ala a volume knob. This is why it's confusing. Contrary to Nathan's hypothesis, I'd argue the problem with these dials is that they *don't* adhere to a person's mental model.

If we're talking temperature, a user's mental model is a thermostat. Turn it higher to make your space hotter, turn it lower to make your space cooler. This is the opposite of the fridge dial.

If we're talking volume, a user's mental model is a volume dial on the radio. Turn it higher to make it louder, turn it lower to make it quieter. Again, the opposite of the fridge dial.

But there are dials where this does have a better correlation. A fan, for instance. Any fan with a dial control will match this mental model: the higher the humber, the more power (and, the cooler you'll feel).

So that's the actual problem, there is no one mental model that makes sense here. Yes, everyone has a fridge, but:

- people rarely adjust their fridge's temperature
- most fridges (aside from some modern ones) offer up no user feedback to tell you if you're making things warmer or colder.

So most of us have never formed a consistent mental model of how a fridge dial works like we have with plenty of other devices we use daily.

To answer the **why was it designed this way?** question, I can't. I don't know why. But my guess is the same as Tohester's. It *wasn't* designed. It was merely the decision of one person at one time that stuck it in there and the rest just followed.

Fortunately, things are getting better for us fridge owners. Many fridges today now have actual temperature controls:

[image]

This matches a universal mental model: higher number = higher temperature.

Answer (score 3):

Fridge temperature thermostat dials are just the worst. I want my next fridge to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: cute, but a happy snowman would actually be *too* cold for the food. :)

Comment: -1 You would need a big dial for the drawings to be clear for anyone looking at it for the first time, or someone more elderly or with poor vision.